# How to make cascading drop-down list using just one class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've already saw examples of that perfectly working but with two separate classes but I'm trying to do a cascading drop-down list just using a single class using ASP.NET MVC.

My class:

```
namespace e_Recarga.Models
{
    public class Estacao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Distribuidora { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "Região")]
        public string Regiao { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "Localização")]
        public string Localizacao { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Disponibilidade")]
        public int Disponibilidade_Postos { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Reserva> Reservas { get; set; }

    }
}



 namespace e_Recarga.Models
{
    public class Reserva
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Utilizador Utilizador{ get; set; }
        public Estacao Estacao { get; set; }
        public byte EstacaoId { get; set; }


    }
}
```

So in the controller I have everything get from the Database and returning it to the view.

```
public class ReservaController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ReservaController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var estacoes = _context.Estacoes.ToList();


        var estacoesDistinct = estacoes.GroupBy(x => x.Regiao ).Select(x => x.First());


        var viewModel = new NovaReservaViewModel
        {
            Estacoes = estacoesDistinct

        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

In the view in terms of HTML I have the drop-down lists already implemented, but I think I need to have a javascript to do the cascading stuff.

```
    @model e_Recarga.ViewModels.NovaReservaViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}


<h2>Nova Reserva</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Reserva"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Regiao)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Id, new SelectList(Model.Estacoes, "Id", "Regiao"), "Escolha a Região", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <select id="regiao"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Distribuidora)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Id, new SelectList(Model.Estacoes, "Id", "Distribuidora"), "Escolha a Região", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <select id="distribuidora"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Nome)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Id, new SelectList(Model.Estacoes, "Id", "Nome"), "Escolha a Estação", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Reserva.Estacao.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

How can I do that?

I've tried the following javascript code:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Get a list of categories and a list of products of the first category.
            $.getJSON('/home/GetRegioes', null, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $('#regiao').append('<option value=' +
                        this.Estacao + '>' + this.Regiao + '</option>');
                });
                $.getJSON('/home/GetDistribuidoras', { intRegiaoId: $('#regiao').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#distribuidora').append('<option value=' +
                            this.Estacao + '>' + this.Distribuidora + '</option>');
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error getting products!');
                });
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error getting categories!');
            });

            // Dropdown list change event.
            $('#regiao').change(function () {
                $('#distribuidora option').remove();
                $.getJSON('/home/GetRegiao', { intRegiaoId: $('#regiao').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#distribuidora').append('<option value=' +
                            this.Distribuidora + '>' + this.ProductName + '</option>');
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error getting products!');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Please shared what you have trying.

Comment: Attached the javascript code